# How to compile code from other compilers in VS 2017

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, cross-compiling

I have downloaded a source code and can't get my head around to how can I compile it/open it in VS 2017. It should have been straight forward but nothing worked until you create a new project. If I just open a C file in VS, it just show me the file and there's no way to run it. Imagine I wrote a simple Hello World in C and I have its C file. How could I open and run it in VS? The only way I found was to create a new project and copy/paste the code from my C file into the newly generated file by VS. This gets extremely inefficient with large projects having multiple C/h files :/

Comment: if this is a cmake-project, cmake can generate a visual studio solution for you.

Comment: a little guide on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should Create a New project -> Visual C++ -> Empty Project. After that, you will see in the solution explorer (Resource files, Header files, and Source files) folders. Right click on Header files and Then Add -> Add existing items, Then you can select multiple header files. Follow for source files same as header files that you Added

Comment: Greattt (Y). Works.